# What is the best way to embed multiple payloads in the "Message" object in spring integration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

In my spring integration application, I would like to start the pipe with a pdf file input, then retrieve some values from db, perform some transformation and finally format it into a xml message. So for the pdf file and db values I have to hold them throughout the whole pipe. I know I could put either one of them into the Header but it seems to me that it's not the best way to go because it's the actually information for my application but not some kind of metadata that should be regarded as header info. Any thoughts?

Comment: And why should that be multiple payloads? Simply construct a new message which includes a single payload that holds the pdf and values from the db.

Comment: I don't understand how you can inject two different kinds of objects into a single payload. When I first obtain the pdf object and construct the Message, then I pass it to the next Transformer, I can only transform/update the values there. How should I do to inject another object, say hashtable into the Message in this transformer such that the next node can retrieve both pdf object and hashtable?

Comment: You don't inject 2 different kind of objects. YOu create a single object which acts as a wrapper around both object (basically a single object having to attributes). This is what you can update/change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general it's OK to do it via MessageHeaders: it's your application and your domain. So, everything in your hands.
From other side you can introduce simple domain object for your purpose and have it as a payload. Or use simple `Map`.
In addition it would be interest for your case to use `Tuple` concept:

https://github.com/reactor/reactor/wiki/Tuples

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/wiki/Tuples

HTH